# Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook Client - "Regarding" and "Track in CRM" ribbon buttons ids

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I would like to invoke button click action on the CRM 2011 outlook add-in buttons.
Microsoft provides Excel with all custom button ids, is there such a document for the CRM client?

I've tried already to use outlookspy and iteration CommandBars in code, but with no success.

Does anyone have an idead how to invoke, hide, or in any way attach to this buttons in custom outlook add-in code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Outlook 2010? If so, check here
http://worldofdynamics.blogspot.ca/2011/08/dynamics-crm-2011-customize-crm-outlook.html